# Не могу передать User в свою форму своей модели

Tags: python, django, form

views.py

```
def create_patient(request):
    patient_user = request.user
    form = CreatePatientForm(request.POST, initial={'user': patient_user})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('mainpage')
    else:
        form = CreatePatientForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'patient_user': patient_user}

    return render(request, 'clinic/create_patient.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class CreatePatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
```

User вроде как передается, но обьект Patient не создается. Если не передаю User, а выбираю в ручную его уже в браузере то все работает.

Comment: А вы уверены, что условия во всех ваших if выполняются?